# API to explore Transportation Mode given Geo-Points

Tags: python, openstreetmap, here-api

I’m new to `here-aip`, and I’m not sure if my needs can be addressed via service offering (I'm open to other location like services / utilities).

I have a list of (ordered) geo-points describing a transit (already taken place in the past) and I would like to get a clue of a feasible transportation mode in which this transit had taken place (e.g.: this looks like a train trip!).

**input example :**

| lon | lat |
| --- | --- |
| 121.240436 | 24.952392 |
| 121.24043 | 24.95239 |
| 121.240436 | 24.952392 |
| 121.23966 | 24.952605 |
| 121.23964 | 24.9526 |
| 121.23964 | 24.95227 |
| 121.23964 | 24.95227 |
| 121.239683 | 24.952316 |
| 121.23967 | 24.95232 |
| 121.240149 | 24.951126 |
| 121.24016 | 24.95111 |

I have thought about providing the list of points as a constraint and receive the estimated duration using each transportation mode (then on my side I can compare the possible duration with the actual duration and conclude the transportation mode).

I currently understand that if I provide two points (e.g. *start* and *end*) I can get a duration estimation and route, but I need more then that (e.g. if the actual transit is circular, providing *start point* and *end point* will not be meaningful).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of VIA parameter to define the multiple waypoints while calculating the route.

Please refer the below link for more details.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/dev_guide/topics/use-cases/via.html

And Refer below example which explain how we can use the VIA parameter in the request.

[https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?apikey={YOUR_API_KEY}&origin=52.542948,13.37152&destination=52.523734,13.40671&via=52.529061,13.369288&via=52.522272,13.381991&return=polyline,summary,actions,instructions,turnByTurnActions&transportMode=car&departureTime=2022-04-05T20:45:00-07:00](https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?apikey=%7BYOUR_API_KEY%7D&origin=52.542948,13.37152&destination=52.523734,13.40671&via=52.529061,13.369288&via=52.522272,13.381991&return=polyline,summary,actions,instructions,turnByTurnActions&transportMode=car&departureTime=2022-04-05T20:45:00-07:00)